# var that takes value from properties file is null when actual method is called from Junit instead of value in test.properties file. How to fix?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit4

Method for which test is writen:

```
public class SampleClassA {

    @Value("${aws.s3.bucket}")
    private String bucketName;

    public Object retrieveObject(String fileUUID) {
        Object repoDoc = new Object();
        MetaData metaData = getMetaData(fileUUID);
        repoDoc.setDocumentContent(retrieveFileFromS3(AppUtils.getKeyPath(metaData.getPath(), bucketName, fileUUID)));
        return repoDoc;
    }
}
```

AppUtils method:

```
public final class AppUtils {
    public static String getKeyPath(String path, String bucketName, String fileUUID){        
        if(path.startsWith(bucketName)){
            return (path.replace((bucketName+"/"), "")+"/"+fileUUID);
        } else {
            throw new Exception(ErrorCode.INVALID_PATH);
        }
    }
}
```

My JUnit:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = S3DocumentManagerImpl.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class SampleClassATest {

    @Value("${aws.s3.bucket}")
    private String bucketName;

    String fileUUID;

    @Spy
    SampleClassA sampleClassA1;

    @InjectMocks
    SampleClassA sampleClassA;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
    }

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        fileUUID = "TestFileUUID";
        repoObj = new Object();
        metaData = new MetaData();
        bucketName = "testBucket";
    }

    @Test
    public void retrieveObjectSuccessTest() throws Exception {
        metaData = CreateObjectsForEntityStub.createMetaDataModel();
        doReturn(metaData).when(sampleClassA1).getMetaData(fileUUID);
        when(repository.findById(fileUUID)).thenReturn(Optional.of(metaData));
        //Here Bucket Name has Value form application-test.properties
        doReturn(null).when(sampleClassA1).retrieveFileFromS3(AppUtils.getKeyPath(metaData.getPath(), bucketName, fileUUID));
        //When called from below bucketName is null
        repoObj = sampleClassA.retrieveObject(fileUUID);
        assertEquals(repoObj.getRepositoryDocumentId(), fileUUID);
    }
}
```

When called from Mockito the value for bucketName exists and is picked from my applications-test.properties whereas when the actual method is called from the test the bucketName is null. Which causes my test to fail with a null pointer exception when it reaches AppUtils.getKeyPath(). How to fix this unit test?

Comment: Because you are creating a new instance instead of using the spring configured instance.

Comment: @M.Deinum I removed the assignment of value to bucketName from the before for my  test. But still same behavior.

Comment: That doesn't matter the `SampleClassA` used in your test is not a spring managed instance so it won't be processed by spring.

Comment: @M.Deinum can you guide me towards the right way to do this.

Comment: From my point of view your test simply doesn't make sense, nor do I get what you are trying to test.